# summing up / assigning bits in verilog

Tags: verilog, bit

I'm beginner in verilog coding and on the search for a smart way to bring bits in order.

I have 60 notes (5 octaves à 12 notes):

```
 output [4:0] c_notes,        
 output [4:0] cs_notes,
 output [4:0] d_notes,
 output [4:0] ds_notes,
 output [4:0] e_notes,
 output [4:0] f_notes,
 output [4:0] fs_notes,
 output [4:0] g_notes,
 output [4:0] gs_notes,
 output [4:0] a_notes,
 output [4:0] as_notes,
 output [4:0] b_notes
```

Which should be assigned to just one bus 
`notes[59:0]`

but in right order: c[4], cs[4], d[4], ds[4], e[4] ... a[0],as[0],b[0]

Would be thankful for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a concatenation, not summing.

```
notes = {c[4], cs[4], d[4], ds[4], e[4] ... a[0],as[0],b[0]};
```

See section 11.4.12 Concatenation operators in the IEEE SystemVerilog 1800-2017 LRM.

You can slightly simplify this using a `for` loop.

```
logic [59:0] notes;
for (int ii=0;ii<5;ii++)
     notes[ii+:5] = {c[ii], cs[ii], d[ii], ds[ii], e[ii]};
```

To do it this way, `notes` must be a variable not a wire.

Comment: Thanks, concatenation sounds better. Just wondering if there might be an easier way than writing down all 60 bits in a row, kind of a transposing or for loop.. ?

Comment: Updated answer using a `for` loop,